# Temporary table in t-sql with delete table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Is there way to create a temporary table with just one column in t-sql, load it and retrieve data? Let me explain...

I have a sproc like this:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + cast(MonthYear as varchar(10)) FROM vCountByMonthYear    where 
    SiteGUID = @SiteGuid 
    and 
    MonthYear BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StopDate 
    ORDER BY '],[' + cast(MonthYear as varchar(10)) FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 2, '') + ']' 

     SET @query = N'SELECT Wuc,LineCount, ' + @cols +' FROM (SELECT Wuc,MonthYear,LineCount,Value,OrderBy FROM vCountByMonthYear 
     where SiteGUID = ' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(nvarchar(36), @SiteGuid) + CHAR(39) + 
     ' and MonthYear BETWEEN ' 
     + CHAR(39) 
     + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@StartDate )
     + CHAR(39) 
     + ' AND ' 
     + CHAR(39) 
     + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@StopDate )
     + CHAR(39) 
     + ' ) p 
     PIVOT ( Sum ([Value] ) FOR MonthYear IN ( '+ @cols +' ) ) AS pvt ORDER BY Wuc,OrderBy' 

     execute(@query)
```

If I modify the view things get all messed up but I need to get additional info from that view - an EventId field. If add it to this query my results are all bad, so I thought I can create a temporaty table and insert what I need, then from a different sproc that would always run immediatelly afterwards would query the temp table and delete it.

Is that doable? How can you delete a table in the same sproc you just queried? I am I over thinking this?

Thanks,
Risho

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to side-step an issue that should be solvable and instead introduce the temp table.  It would be good to understand why the view can't be modified, and why the field can't be added to your existing query without messing up the results...

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: I've added the column to the sproc above and the result was incorect in terms of how the output. In this case the pivot is used to display time periods as column headers that are part of the data row. The view consists of seven other views that are "UNION"-ed together and the line count is value holder for calculated values. Clearly you must see that I'm not and expert here otherwise I would not post this, as I didn't write any of the views/sprocs - merely trying to make modification.

Comment: Also how is @MichaelFrederickson comment usefull to this posting and deserves 2 upvotes is beyond me. How can you make the assesment what should be "solvable"? You don't work, my job, and don't know my situation and experience! And this to averyone who has down-voted my past postings: If you have nothing usefull to say, don't say anything at all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a global temp table (defined with ## instead of #).  Since the exec runs in a different scope than the stored procedure you won't be able to access a temp table defined in the scope of the stored procedure.  You can then access that global temp table in your dynamic query and delete it at the end of the proc.

Everything will then have access to this global table, though, so be careful.

```
CREATE TABLE ##globalTmpTable (EventID INT)
```

Comment: That is what I'm looking into.